# Extract a topic from bag file and save it to another bag file

Tags: ros, rosbag, rosbag-record

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

I have a *.bag file which contains different topics and I would like to extract only a specific topic and record it in a new bag file.

Is it possible?

I've read about a solution which enable users to extract a topic and save its content in a CSV file, but the problem is that I need to have another *.bag file and not CSV.

Is there any solution?

Thank you!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238225/extract-a-topic-from-bag-file-and-save-it-to-another-bag-file/) by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2016-06-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the first example listed for the `rosbag filter` command: http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#filter

```
rosbag filter my.bag only-tf.bag "topic == '/tf'"
```

If you want to extract a topic other than `/tf`, simply change that portion of the command.

Note that the expression `topic == '/tf'` is surrounded in double quotes so that it isn't interpreted by the shell, and `/tf` is further enclosed in single quotes because it is a python string literal.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2016-06-28**:
Thank you!!!

**Comment by [petitchamp](https://answers.ros.org/users/39839/petitchamp/) on 2019-02-04**:
Is there any way to extract more than one topic from a bag file?
something like "topic == '/tf1,/tf2'"?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-02-04**:
Yes; you can use any python expression as the filte, so you could do `"topic in ['/topic1', '/topic2']"` or even use python's string or regex matching!